# Compress images with Pillow in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I have a project with Django and I use Pillow to store images in some models, but I want those images to be stored compressed. How can I instruct Pillow to compress the images when they are saved to a model **ImageField**?

This is an example of a model with an **ImageField**:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='photos', verbose_name=_("Album"))
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Photo"))

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Photo")
        verbose_name_plural =_("Photos")

    def __str__(self):
        return "[{}] {}".format(self.pk, self.name)
```

I can see the file once stored, and I can see it has the same size than the original source file.

I am using **Django Rest Framework** to get images from the front-end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override `save` method of the model:

```
from PIL import Image

class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='photos', verbose_name=_("Album"))
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Photo"))

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       instance = super(Photo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       image = Image.open(instance.photo.path)
       image.save(instance.photo.path,quality=20,optimize=True)
       return instance
```

Comment: Can this same result be achieved with the pre_save receiver?

Comment: You need a post_save signal, because you need the instance to be saved before, to have the path of photo.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/), specifically the post_save method. The fastest way to implement it is to write this in the `models.py` file

```py
from PIL import Image
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

class Photo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Name"))
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='photos', verbose_name=_("Album"))
    photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name=_("Photo"))

def image_compressor(sender, **kwargs): 
    if kwargs["created"]:
        with Image.open(kwargs["instance"].photo.path) as photo:
            photo.save(kwargs["instance"].photo.path, optimize=True, quality=50)

post_save.connect(image_compressor, sender=Photo)
```